# Avoid duplicate authors/citation keys in Mendeley

Tags: citations, reference-managers, bibtex

I recently encountered an issue when using Mendeley for generating bib-files. Some of the papers in I would like to use were written by authors with the same Name (but different persons), and published in the same year. The autogeneration in Mendeley therefore returns two keys which are identical, even though the papers are not. I caught that issue too late after getting a warning from `biber`, and now have to go through the document again to replace the citation keys. Are there options in Mendeley to check matching keys beforehand?

Moreover, a similar issue with duplicates for authors can arise in the database itself. If an author called "Marty McFly" is listed as "McFly, Marty" in one paper, and "McFly, M." in a second one, are there options to list those papers and de-duplicate the author (i.e. change "McFly, Marty" into "McFly, M." in the internal database), without having to go through the list of all authors?

If this question is not appropriate for academia.stackexchange, feel free to move it, but I assumed it might fit best here due to several other questions also covering Mendeley.

Comment: Hmm, when I import two papers with the same author and year into Mendeley (specifically, Mendeley Desktop on Mac), it assigns them keys like 'Smith2020' and 'Smith2020a' precisely to avoid this problem. I use the setting (under Preferences->BibTex) 'Create one BibTex file for my whole library,' which may be important to force Mendeley to deal with duplicates.

Comment: @Rococo: It is not the same author, unfortunately, it is only the name of the author which is identical. I.e. one paper was published by "McFly, Marty", and the second one by "McFly, Dave", both in 1985, then Mendeley will generate two identical keys with "mcfly1985", even though both persons published different things.

Comment: Nonetheless, it appears that my version of Mendeley would make one of these as mcfly1985a. Specifically, just now I searched Google scholar for 'Smith 2000,' and downloaded two random articles with a Smith as the first author. For the first one I imported it gave it the key Smith2000, and for the second Smith2000a.